# Properties of improper integral (showing that: $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx.$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ is integrable on every segment $[r,\infty)$ where $r>0$. Let $\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ and $\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges. Why in this case we can conclude that $$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx.$$

Can anyone explain it rigorously?
Maybe I don't know a definition.

Comment: I saw this question posted by you yesterday...... and yes it can be explained rigorously, think about what the integral means geometrically, if I have 2 squares and sum the area it's the same as putting the two squares together and taking the resulting rectangle's area.

Comment: It's good but I don't how to prove it strictly! :(

Comment: @AlecTeal That's not pretty rigorous tho...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, Can you show rigorous proof please? I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Have you already shown that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{ d}x = \int_{a}^{c}f(x)\text{d}x + \int_{c}^{b}f(x)\text{ d}x$$
for any $c \in [a, b]$, as long as $f$ is integrable in $[a, c]$ and $[b, c]$? If so, then the proof is easy: take $b \to \infty$, $c = 1$, $a = 0$.

Comment: @Clarinetist As $$\int_a^\infty f(x)dx= \lim_{b\to \infty} \int_a^b f(x)dx$$

By definition (just adding for OP).

Comment: @Clarinetist, in my example $f$ is integrable on any $[r,\infty)$ but not at [0,\infty)! This partition into two integrals is true for Riemann proper integrals. Can you explain your partition?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. Hmm. I'm not sure how to approach this, but I imagine some sort of limit argument would work... maybe topology might be involved, but I know almost nothing about topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should help to know that, given an integrable function $f$, it can be said that for $a<b$ and $c \in (a,b)$
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{c} f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{b} f(x)dx$$
So then of course we can then just take $a=0$, $c=1<b$.
$$\int_{0}^{b} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx+\int_{1}^{b} f(x)dx$$
And let $b \to \infty$.
Proof of this property is trivial. Via the fundamental theory of calculus we know that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a), F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$
Therefore we have
$$\int_{a}^{c} f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{b} f(x)dx=F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c)=F(b)-F(a)$$
$$=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$$

Comment: in my example $f$ is integrable on any $[r,\infty)$ but not at [0,\infty)! This partition into two integrals is true for Riemann proper integrals. Can you explain your partition?

Comment: Well assuming that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ is a defined convergent value requires integratability on the interval $[0, \infty)$, does it not?

Comment: I know that $\int \limits_{0}^{1}fdx$ and $\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}fdx$ are exists. Why $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}fdx$ woulbe sum of these? Only this question excites me.

Comment: And if not that, by asserting that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ you are saying that $f$ is integratable on $[0,\infty)$. Even if you don't assert it explicitly, it is enough to then use that definition to conclude something about $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you :(

Comment: What definition? Asserting what?

Comment: I added proof for that sum property; now you should be able to see why we can define $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$, knowing $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)dx$

Comment: Sorry but I think that function $F(x)=\int \limits f(x)dx$ is little bit not accurate. How you get that $F(b)-F(a)=\int \limits_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$?

Comment: That is a direct consequence of the fundamental theory of calculus. It's pretty much the basis of modern calculus.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: @WillFisher Your justification of $\int_a^b=\int_a^c+\int_c^b$ is not correct. You can't apply the fundamental theorem of calculus in the way you did, if you just assume $f$ to be integrable.

Comment: The context implies it being integratable.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, Dear! Why his justification is not right?

Comment: @RaheemNajib Because $f$ is integrable does not mean that $f$ has an antiderivative $F$. For instance $f(x) =\operatorname{sign}(x)$ is integrable on all intervals but does not possess an antiderivative on an interval containing $0$.

Comment: @AndreiKh, Why it has not antiderivative on an interval containing $0$? Can you explain it please?

Comment: @RaheemNajib Because the derivative of this "antiderivative" $F$ would be $f(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x)$, which has a jump discontinuity at $x= 0$. But by Darboux Theorem the derivative of a function cannot have jump discontinuities.

Answer (score 3):

I think is the case that you "don't know a definition" (as you said) because there is nothing to prove here (at least, in Tom Apostol's approach).

If the integrals
$$\int \limits_{0}^{c}f(x)dx\quad \text{and}\quad \int \limits_{c}^{\infty}f(x)dx\tag{1}$$
are both convergent for some $c\in(0,\infty)$, then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int \limits_{0}^{c}f(x)dx+ \int \limits_{c}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
**by definition**. What you can prove if you want is "that the choice of $c$ is unimportant" (Apostol's words), that is, the value of $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ doesn't depends on $c$ (provided that both integrals in $(1)$ are convergent).

In your case, 
$$\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\quad \text{and}\quad \int \limits_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
are both convergent and thus
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int \limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+ \int \limits_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
by definition of $\int_0^\infty$.

*As I said, this answer follows the [Apostol's approach](http://www.mif.vu.lt/~stepanauskas/AM1/Tom%20Apostol%20-%20Calculus%20vol.1%20-%20One-variable%20Calculus,%20with%20an%20Introduction%20to%20Linear%20Algebra%20%281975%29.pdf) (see section 10.23).*

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed $D$  such that $[D,\infty)\subset$ dom$(f)$  define $$(1)....\quad \int_D^{\infty}f(x) dx=\lim_{Y\to \infty}\int_D^Y f(x) dx   $$ provided that this limit exists. . If $\int_A^{\infty}f(x) dx$  exists for fixed $A$ then for fixed $B>A$  let $$\int_A^Bf(x) dx= C.$$ Then $C$ is fixed and $$(2)....\quad\int_A^{\infty}f(x) dx=\lim_{Y\to \infty}\int_A^Y f(x) dx=\lim_{Y\to \infty} \left ( \int_A^B f(x) dx+\int_B^Y f(x) dx\right )=$$ $$=\lim_{Y\to \infty}\left (C+\int_B^Y f(x) dx \right )=\left (C+\lim_{Y\to \infty}\int_B^Y f(x) dx\right )= \left (\int_A^B f(x) dx+\int _B^{\infty} f(x) dx\right ).$$The first equality in (2) is by (1) with $D=A$, and the last equality, above, is by (1) with $D=B.$ In particular let $A=0,\; B=1.$